# Unable to find dialect of hibernate in resteasy application

Tags: hibernate, rest, oracle10g

I have a hibernate project which interacts with Oracle 10g database, and have a seperate dynamic web project in which we have defined rest web services..

Now when we make a call from the web service project to make a query into the database via the hibernate project using sessionfactory object its showing an error saying-

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at com.pandora.dbmodels.root.util.HibernateHelper.getFactory(HibernateHelper.java:60)
    at com.pandora.dbmodels.root.util.HibernateHelper.openSession(HibernateHelper.java:112)
    at com.pandora.dbmodels.root.util.HibernateHelper.getSession(HibernateHelper.java:124)
    at test.services.Service.searchAd(Service.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:217)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:206)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:503)`

However we have already specified hibernate dialect in hibernate properties file - "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect"

Please let me know of a solution as soon as possible..

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Did you misspell the property name?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: Oracle10g
@Jeremy: no i didnt.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: 10g Release 1 (10.1)

Comment: @Anand - OK this might not help then, but I had problems with 10.2.0.2 jar and upgraded to 10.2.0.5 and it solved my problem.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: hey the problem is that when i make the database call from the hibernate project it works.. but when i make the call from a web service... its showing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey found the solution... 
i needed to programmatically set the property of the hibernate dialect in the code...

Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .addClass(org.hibernate.auction.Bid.class)
    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect")